# Can Angular views and html use HTTP whilst JSON RestAPI calls use HTTPS?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, https

Thinking about HTTPS, it is a compute-intensive protocol and one should only use it where necessary.  I'm working on a web application and I will be using Angular.js MVC on the client side, calling into WebAPI REST Api returning JSON.

When I think about it I do not need to encrypt the HTML, the client-side javascript or styles sheet etc.  After initial handshake only the data calls to the REST Api need encrypting.

Do other people do this?  Are there any pitfalls or caveats?

Comment: You DO need your initial route and template to be loaded with HTTPS, else the browser will complain.

Comment: Why?  Is this cross origin resource sharing attack thing?

Comment: Much appreciated :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a great [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Security/MixedContent/How_to_fix_website_with_mixed_content) article detailing their restrictions and why they exist.

Their recommendation is to always stick strictly to either HTTP or HTTPS.

Also, I suspect that browsers and web servers will greatly minimize the impact of encrypting the data over ssl on subsequent calls.  I suspect if you profile it you'll find the impact minimal/non-measurable.